# How to enable horizontal scroll bar in WebView

Tags: android, android-layout

I am loading a string of text and an image to the Webview. Upon zooming i want to make both the vertical and horizontal bars to appear.

i am using

```
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

and

```
    wvEditorial = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvEditorial);
    wvEditorial.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    wvEditorial.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    wvEditorial.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

but when i zoom-in the words get arranged bellow one another instead of creating the horizontal scroll bar and i have no option to slide horizontally

i also tried

```
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

help ??

Answer (score 1):

you should use ScrollView  .

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    ndroid:layout_height="fill_parent" >
// your text and image layout in a common layout .

</scrollView>
```

Comment: but the problem is i am directly loading the image from internet (the text too). In that AsyncTask i get the text and the image url. if i use a scrollview i have to use a 2nd AsyncTask to download the image too. i wouldn't prefer that

Comment: try to set  wvEditorial.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); and remove  wvEditorial.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); , because webview default provide zoom control .

Answer (score 0):

set webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true).